# Delete TFVC Azure Devops Branch API

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfvc

I'm looking and can't find any TFVC API's, it's all for GIT. I'm needing to delete a branch and then create a new branch from an existing branch in my TFVC repo. Therefore, I'm looking for an API\PowerShell that will accomplish this. I'm wanting an API so that I can add this to my pipeline to perform automatically. PLEASE HELP

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There are limited TFVC REST APIs. Branch management is not available via REST.

TFVC is considered feature complete and is not receiving additional investment from Microsoft.

You can use the `tf` CLI to manage branches, or use the old .NET SOAP client libraries.

Comment: Thanks. How can I use the 'TF' commands on a pipeline? for example to delete a branch and then create a new one based off an existing branch?